# Python - TypeError: Tuple indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64

Tags: python, numpy

Getting this error for something that looks simple. Help would be appreciated.

finaltbl is a pandas df with col1prelim, col2prelim, and col3prelim, which have values ranging between 0 and 1 in float format.

```
finaltbl['col1'] = np.nan
finaltbl['col2'] = np.nan
finaltbl['col3'] = np.nan
coldict = {'col1':'col1prelim', 'col2':'col2prelim', 'col3':'col3prelim'}

for k, v in coldict.items():
    finaltbl.at[0, k] = 1
    finaltbl.at[1, k] = np.mean(finaltbl.loc[0, v], finaltbl.loc[1, v])
```

This returns `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64`

However this works:

```
for k, v in coldict.items():
    finaltbl.at[0, k] = 1
    finaltbl.at[1, k] = (finaltbl.loc[0, v] + finaltbl.loc[1, v])/2
```

How do I change my average/mean calc above to work? I need to later on use 3 or 4 inputs rather than 2 and would like to be able to use a mean formula or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

When you perform numpy.mean() on those values the result is stored in Numpy's internal numpy.float type which can not be use as an indexer. You need to cast your variable to and integer.

For scalar values, int() is fine -which is your case. For float64 ndarrays, you need to use Numpy's astype() method.

Comment: There's nothing he needs to cast as integer.  Rather he needs to pass the correct arguments to `np.mean`.

Answer (score 1):

Make a small dataframe:

```
In [17]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12.).reshape(4,3))                                   
In [18]: df                                                                               
Out[18]: 
     0     1     2
0  0.0   1.0   2.0
1  3.0   4.0   5.0
2  6.0   7.0   8.0
3  9.0  10.0  11.0
```

Try to use `mean` as you do, showing the FULL traceback:

```
In [19]: np.mean(df.loc[0,1],df.loc[1,1])                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-19b913c69c93> in <module>
----> 1 np.mean(df.loc[0,1],df.loc[1,1])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
   3113             pass
   3114         else:
-> 3115             return mean(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, **kwargs)
   3116 
   3117     return _methods._mean(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in _mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     60 
     61     is_float16_result = False
---> 62     rcount = _count_reduce_items(arr, axis)
     63     # Make this warning show up first
     64     if rcount == 0:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in _count_reduce_items(arr, axis)
     53     items = 1
     54     for ax in axis:
---> 55         items *= arr.shape[ax]
     56     return items
     57 

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64
```

Note that error occurs when trying to use the axis variable.  If `arr` is a numpy array, then `arr.shape` is a tuple.  `(1,2,3)[1.0]` would produce the same error message.

From `np.mean` docs:

```
Signature: np.mean(a, axis=None, ...)
```

the first argument is an array (or something that can be made into an array).  The second is an axis value - `None`, an integer, or a tuple of integers.  You instead give it an element of your dataframe, evidently one that is a float.

So you need to give `np.mean` the correct arguments.  For example a list of dataframe elements:

```
In [22]: np.mean([df.loc[0,1],df.loc[1,1]])                                               
Out[22]: 2.5
```

===

Summary:

- look at the full traceback, and show it to us.  It can have valuable clues as to what is wrong
- read the docs of functions that you use.

Answer (score 1):

@hpaulj: TL;DR

np.mean typically only requires one argument.  The error caused by inputting

```
np.mean(finaltbl.loc[0, v], finaltbl.loc[1, v])
```

will be eliminated if you put the 2 arguments into a single array using square brackets

```
np.mean([finaltbl.loc[0, v], finaltbl.loc[1, v]])
```